# Cannot connect to or ping network printer

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, printer, ping

I've just bought my first network printer and I'm having problems setting it up. I've walked through the setup procedure, and it's correctly connected to my home wifi, and it can connect to the internet, however, I can't see the printer from either my Windows laptop, my Macbook Pro or my iPad.

The printer has an IP address, but I can't ping that IP address from either my Windows laptop or Macbook Pro. If I run `arp -a` on either machine, I see something like:

```
? (192.168.1.106) at (incomplete) on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
```

I can happily ping my router and my NAS, and `arp -a` shows ip address and mac address for this, but the printer shows `incomplete`. One thing I've noticed is that my NAS has a static IP. I don't know if this makes a difference - I can ping with a static IP, but not ping anything that's been set by DHCP. Although if I give my printer a static IP, it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Surprisingly, I also can't ping between my Windows and MBP laptops, something I hadn't noticed before. If I set up arp routes manually, adding IP address and MAC address on both laptops, ping starts working. If I add an arp route from my laptop to the printer, it still fails (presumably because I can't do it at both ends)

I can also telnet into the CLI of the router (a TG582n) and can see the arp table is full and correct, for all IP addresses in the house, including the laptops and printer. I can even ping the printer, with no problems.

There is no security software, such as firewall or AV software installed on my Mac (I'm surprised the firewall is off by default!) and the Win laptop doesn't have anything other than a default set up of Windows 8.1 built in firewall and malware Defender.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on? Why would the laptops not be able to ping the printer, or each other?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've got it working. I had to telnet into the CLI of the TG582n and run `nat ifconfig intf Multicast translation enabled`. I have to confess that I don't really know what this means...